# Apache Beam Python - How can I infer an automatic schema based on the data loaded

Tags: python, google-bigquery, schema, apache-beam

I have an Apache Beam pipeline in python where I'm reading data from a excel stored in GCS and writing the data in BigQuery.

The problem is that the columns from the excel is always changing, so I can't infer an manual schema and I need to write to BigQuery in the same order of columns that the excel file.

I was writing to bigquery using the SCHEMA_AUTODETECT option, but it is saving the columns in a different order that in the excel file. How can I read the data, automatically infer an schema and then pass this schema to save the data in BigQuery?

Here is my pipeline:

```
def run_pipeline(input_file, tab_bottlenecks, output_table_bottlenecks, temp_location):

    # Config Pipeline Options
    pipeline_options = {
    'project': 'xxxx'}
    
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions.from_dictionary(pipeline_options)
    
    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:

        import pandas as pd

        # Reading file and some transformations bottlenecks
        input_data = (
            pipeline
            | 'Read From GCS' >> beam.Create([input_file])
            | 'Read Excel' >> beam.FlatMap(lambda file: pd.read_excel(file, tab_bottlenecks).to_dict('records'))
            | 'Handle NaN' >> beam.Map(handle_nan)
        )

        # Write to BigQuery Bottlenecks
        input_data | 'Write To BigQuery -> Bottlenecks' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            output_table_bottlenecks,
            schema='SCHEMA_AUTODETECT',
            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
            custom_gcs_temp_location = temp_location
        )
        
        # Create Template in Cloud Storage
        pipeline.run().wait_until_finish()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_file = 'gs://xxx/xxx.xlsx'
    tab_bottlenecks = 'Lista'
    output_table_bottlenecks = 'xx:xx.xx'
    temp_location = 'gs://xxx'
    run_pipeline(input_file, tab_bottlenecks, output_table_bottlenecks, temp_location)
```

I tried to insert data with an automatic schema, but I loose the order of the fields. I need to save the data into BigQuery in the same order that the excel file

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround is to update the schema later: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas. Another idea is to get the schema first and use it as the side input for Bigquery write.